# How to set Rtools PATH for R

Tags: r, rtools

I am having trouble with `rtools`. `Sys.which("make")` yields an empty vector (working from `R Studio`)

`Sys.which("make")`

> ""

This is my R Version

```
R.Version()$version.string
```

> [1] "R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10)"

Apparently, this is an issue with my `PATH`.

```
Sys.getenv("PATH")
```

> C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\...\Miniconda3;C:\Users\...\Miniconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Users\...\Miniconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\...\Miniconda3\Library\bin;C:\Users\...\Miniconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\;C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\;C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin"

I have tried to set the `PATH` to `rtools` the following.

I have created a `~/.Renviron` file

```
PATH="${RTOOLS40_HOME}\usr\bin;${PATH}"
```

I also have tried this one

```
file.edit(file.path("~", ".Rprofile"))
Sys.setenv(PATH = paste("C:/Rtools/bin", Sys.getenv("PATH"), sep=";"))
```

However, still no luck.
How do I set the path to `rtools`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I solved it:

1. By looking at my `PATH` variable, which you get through

`Sys.getenv("PATH")`

I saw that it pointed `rtools` to `c:\rtools40\`. However, this should be `c:\rtools40\usr\bin`. I edited the environment Variable accordingly. [Here is an instruction how to edit the environment variables on windows.](https://www.h3xed.com/windows/how-to-add-to-and-edit-windows-path-variable)

2. I also added this to the `.Renviron` file:

`PATH="${RTOOLS40_HOME}\usr\bin;${PATH}"`

The `.Renviron` file should be created/located accordingly to this location

```
Sys.getenv("HOME")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. My workaround: Upon checking `Sys.getenv("PATH")` I found that I had a different verison of rtools (42 instead of 43 as listed there). I uninstalled the wrong version and downloaded rtools43. Now it works.